# Zero as first argument in IIFE

Tags: javascript, babeljs

In `babeljs` v6.5.1,

```
class Foo {}
```

compiles to

```
"use strict";

var _classCallCheck2 = require("babel-runtime/helpers/classCallCheck");

var _classCallCheck3 = _interopRequireDefault(_classCallCheck2);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

var Foo = function Foo() {
  (0, _classCallCheck3.default)(this, Foo);
};
```

What's the point of the `0` in `(0, _classCallCheck3.default)(this, Foo);`?

In the online [`babeljs` repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20Foo%20%7B%7D), which probably has a different `babeljs` version, that line is simply `_classCallCheck(this, Foo);`, and they seem to do the same thing. What's the difference between these two statements?

Comment: Is "argument" the right term for me to use in the title? I have a feeling it's not, but I don't know what the correct term would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `0` is ignored. It is there solely to allow the comma operator to evaluate `_classCallCheck3.default` and get the function without `this` being `_classCallCheck3`.